# Можно, пожалуйста, пример хотя бы одного теста к данной функции? Использую jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, jest

Можно, пожалуйста, пример хотя бы одного теста к данной функции? Использую jest.

```
    async registration(req, res, next) {
      const {login, password} = req.body;

      const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 5);
      const admin = await Admin.create({login, password: hashPassword});
      const token = generateAdminJwt(admin.id, admin.login);
      return res.json({token});
    }
```

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: Я новичок в написании тестов, не понимаю, как это должно выглядеть в данном случае. Предугадываю вопрос о том, умею ли я гуглить. Я гуглила, но всё, что я пыталась адаптировать, не работает. Мне бы хотя бы пример или объяснение, чтобы действовать дальше)